# Nested oneToMany doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've got 3 class:

```
class A {
 // some variables...
 // even some @OneToMany List<MyOtherObject> variables
}

class B {
  @OneToMany
  List<C> cList;
  // other...
}

class C {
 // some variables...
}
```

And everything works fine with this configuration but:
When I added to class A:
`@OneToMany List<B>` there is an spring error saying something about classpath (nothing about hibernate exceptions).

In brief:
I want to achieve `List<List<MyObject>>`

Comment: You'er using Hibernate or jpa?

Comment: I'm using spring boot with hibernate

Comment: Can you show us the error.

Answer (score 0):

There was a nested 'org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException' that I didn't notice.
Changing FetchType from EAGER to LAZY solved my problem.